# change background colour of flex-flow wrapped list

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list that doesn't have a predetermined number of items but I need to control the height of it's container so I am splitting the list using flex-flow: wrap column.  The list is initially hidden and revealed using jQuery slideToggle().

As it is the background of the list is transparent so I am trying to find a way of colouring it and giving it rounded corners but the containing div is only the width of the first column.

How can I make the containing div be the same width as the list so I can style it properly?

```js
$("#audit_search_btn").click(function () {
    $("#image_list").slideToggle();
});

$("#image_list").click(function () {
    $("#image_list").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#audit_search_btn {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: $lilac;
    border: $lilac-border;
    color: $btn-text;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:200px;
}
#image_list {
    height: auto;
    top:30px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 99999;

}
  ul{
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: flex;
       -webkit-flex-flow: wrap column;
       flex-flow: wrap column;
       max-height: 100px;
  }
    .audit_search_jump {
        margin-top:20px; 
        width:100%; 
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="audit_search_jump">
  <div id="image_list">
    <ul>
      <!-- while loop populating list -->
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="audit_search_btn">Image Quick Jump</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `left` and `right` position coordinates to the `div`.

Example:

```js
$("#audit_search_btn").click(function() {
  $("#image_list").slideToggle();
});

$("#image_list").click(function() {
  $("#image_list").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#audit_search_btn {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid lilac;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
}

#image_list {
  height: auto;
  top: 30px;
  
  /* added */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
}

ul {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: wrap column;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  max-height: 60px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.audit_search_jump {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="audit_search_jump">
  <div id="image_list">
    <ul>
      <!-- while loop populating list -->
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="audit_search_btn">Image Quick Jump</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for that but it makes the containing div the same width as it's container.  I would like the div to be the same width as it's contents, the list

Comment: @tatty27 I don't think it's possible without setting a `right` coordinate or a `width`. You could do it with jQuery though